# Unable to index typescript object

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is what I have:

```
export const ID1 = "id1";
export const ID2 = "id2";
export const ID3 = "id3";

export const MAPPING1 = "MAPPING1";
export const MAPPING2 = "MAPPING2";
export const MAPPING3 = "MAPPING3";

export const MAPPINGS = {
    ID1: MAPPING1,
    ID2: MAPPING2,
    ID3: MAPPING3
};
```

```
const finalMapping = MAPPINGS[key as keyof typeof MAPPINGS] || "NOTFOUND"
```

where `key` is a string. I've printed out test values like so:

```
console.log("key = " + key + " with type: " + (typeof key));
// prints this: key = ID1 with type: string
```

But `finalMapping` ends up always being `NOTFOUND` for me. Why am I unable to index the `MAPPINGS` object properly?

Comment: Unable to reproduce [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAkgEQIwwLwwEQEsAmSMDcAsAFCiSyIBMamuVhp508CAzLdjm4yU+CwCyAQQAKouADkA4inQYR4qbN7NYiiTJryNyhsTID1YzdI46Tyngf4UYumQGVaAb1IwPrJAC57lmUgANO6e1L4O0lTBJJ6sbOH+ZqQAvjaGdgDWAKYAnpyI+GlqMABmWGAAhgA2ghUADnXlAOa0EY4A2tl5FRAwXSAlMFA5dVkDfkpOALowAD6zmJIA8gAqAGJLAKqSCLy2ECBVWQB0VSBNABRllTX1jWBNAJSkQA), there must be more code that influences the output

Comment: @kellys Not sure why reproducing it doesn't work, but I found the fix. Posting an answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this works, but it does:

```
export const MAPPINGS = {
    ID1: MAPPING1,
    ID2: MAPPING2,
    ID3: MAPPING3
};
```

to

```
export const MAPPINGS = {
    [ID1]: MAPPING1,
    [ID2]: MAPPING2,
    [ID3]: MAPPING3
};
```

Comment: Your first `MAPPINGS` has keys which are literally `"ID1"`, `"ID2"`, and `"ID3"`, while your second one has keys which are `"id1"`, `"id2"`, and `"id3"`.  That's because the latter is using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).